# Position: absolute и ширина блока

Tags: html, css

Как сделать одинаковую ширину блоков, если для открытых используется position: absolute?
Закрытые имеют ширину 100%, т.к. макет резиновый, т.е. статику прописать нет возможности.

https://yadi.sk/i/fBcNHN5AauXsg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если можно, дайте пример вашего css кода, так немного сложно понять, о чем речь.

Возможно, вам стоит в блоки с position: absolute прописать width: 100% и проверить, что у родительского блока position:relative и тоже ширина 100%. Надеюсь поможет, просто не совсем понял, что вам нужно.

Comment: Вот, это помогло. Спасибо!
Если просто прописать width: 100% у блока с position: absolute, то блок уезжает за пределы экрана.
Если у родителя дописать указанное выше, то получается, как надо.